# Should I purchase health insurance directly, or through my LLC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, health-insurance, north-carolina

I am currently in the market for health insurance and have an LLC with myself as the sole employee. I would like to know the advantages vs the disadvantages to purchasing through my business. Also how would this translate in terms of write-offs [deductions]? NC is the state.

Comment: Generally, small business plans cost less than individual plans and have greater benefits. The tax consequences are the same either way. If you tag your state you can get more specific advice.

Comment: My suggestion is to price the same plan both ways, but I'd not be shocked to find @Rocky's comment correct.  Really have to suggest a local CPA to help you navigate the area you're entering (minimizing tax burden in an LLC).

Answer (score 1):

Shopping for health insurance is like shopping for a new car. You wouldn't just go to one salesman, get a price on a car and make the purchase right there. You want to go to multiple sources to see where you can get the best price.

What you're asking is for someone to do this quoting for you, which is impossible with only knowing you have an LLC and live in NC. Insurance companies need things like ages, medical histories, and level of coverage. In order to determine which is best we would need to know how large your company is, what it's current tax liability is like, and whether you plan on adding more employees. For these reasons, nobody on here can tell you which to choose.

So to your original question, I don't know. But if you are wondering how to decide which one to go with, the answer is do your research. As a small business owner you are probably no stranger to leg work and figuring out things you don't yet understand. Every person, small business owner or not, has to do their own research when it comes to insurance.

Hope this helps you get things sorted out and puts you on your way.